# QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices() doesn't return all available devices, instead return only one on three audio out devices actually exist.Why?

Tags: android, qt, audio, alsa, tinyalsa

**Question:**

**1.** The QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioOutput)) return only one audio device(default device) from three audio out devices. Why?
**Total three audio out devices are available and while checking with ALSA devices verified the output using "tinyplay" utility by command line.
But QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices() doesn't return these three devices, it return only one device(default).**

**Note:**
Used the sample code on qt samples for audiooutput. Only one device returned.

```
m_deviceBox->addItem(defaultDeviceInfo.deviceName(), qVariantFromValue(defaultDeviceInfo));
foreach (const QAudioDeviceInfo &deviceInfo, QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioOutput)) {
if (deviceInfo != defaultDeviceInfo) {
 m_deviceBox->addItem(deviceInfo.deviceName(), qVariantFromValue(deviceInfo));
}
}
```

**2. How to set a particular ALSA device(for eg: card0, device 0) as default audio device?**
In this case QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice() is set as device 0 on sound card2.

Please see below for details........

**System Setup:**

Target Board : iMX6Q Sabre AI

OS : Android M6

Qt : QT 5.8

Android NDK r10

Android SDK : 25.2.5

**Available Sound Cards:**

root@sabreauto_6q:/ # cat /proc/asound/cards

0 [cs42888audio ]: cs42888-audio - cs42888-audio
cs42888-audio
1 [imxspdif ]: imx-spdif - imx-spdif
imx-spdif
2 [imxhdmisoc ]: imx-hdmi-soc - imx-hdmi-soc
imx-hdmi-soc

**Available Sound Devices:**

root@sabreauto_6q:/ # cat /proc/asound/card0/
id pcm0c/ pcm0p/ pcm1c/ pcm1p/

root@sabreauto_6q:/ # cat /proc/asound/card1/
id pcm0c/

root@sabreauto_6q:/ # cat /proc/asound/card2/
id pcm0p/

***Note: Total 3 sound cards and 3 Audio(ALSA) out devices are present.***

**Attempts to test audio out devices:**

Using tinyplay utility sound out verified for whole audio out drivers.

tinyplay test.wav -D 0 -d 0 --> Sound verified.
Note : ALSA device 0 on Sound Card 0 is running to produce sound out.

tinyplay test.wav -D 0 -d 1 --> Sound verified.

tinyplay test.wav -D 2 -d 0 --> Sound verified.

Comment: I guess Qt uses the Android API, and that one has only one active device.

Comment: Audio support in Qt is mediocre at best.